# How to keep UIAlertController when click button?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I make UIAlertController with some textfields and two button. I have button register. How to keep UIAlertController when i click button register. Because after i run some method in button, my UIAlertController close. Please help me keep UIAlertController after i click button register. And how can i validate textfield in UIAlertController?

```
UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Login"
                                                                                                                        message: @"Input username and password"
                                                                                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                                              [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                                                  textField.placeholder = @"username";
                                                  textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                                                  textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
                                                  textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
                                                  textField.text=username;
                                                  textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

                                              }];
                                              [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                                                  textField.placeholder = @"email";
                                                  textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                                                  textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
                                                  textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
                                                  textField.text=email;
                                                  textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

                                              }];
                                              [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                                                  textField.placeholder = @"tell";
                                                  textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                                                  textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
                                                  textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
                                              }];
                                              [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                                                  textField.placeholder = @"address";
                                                  textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                                                  textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
                                                  textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
                                              }];
                                              [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                                                  textField.placeholder = @"city";
                                                  textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                                                  textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
                                                  textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
                                              }];
                                              [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                                                  textField.placeholder = @"national";
                                                  textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                                                  textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
                                                  textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
                                              }];
                                              [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                                                  textField.placeholder = @"postcode";
                                                  textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                                                  textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
                                                  textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
                                              }];
                                              [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                  n++;
                                                  FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
                                                  [loginManager logOut];
                                                  [sender setTitle:@"Login with facebook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                                              }]];
                                              [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Register" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                  NSArray * textfields = alertController.textFields;
                                                  UITextField * usernamefield = textfields[0];
                                                  UITextField * emailfield = textfields[1];
                                                  UITextField * tellfield = textfields[2];
                                                  UITextField * addressfield = textfields[3];
                                                  UITextField * cityfield = textfields[4];
                                                  UITextField * nationalfield = textfields[5];
                                                  UITextField * postcodefield = textfields[6];
                                                  //NSLog(@"%@:%@:%@:%@:%@:%@",usernamefield.text,emailfield.text,tellfield.text,
                                                  //     addressfield.text,cityfield.text,nationalfield.text,postcodefield.text);



                                                  NSInteger success=0;  
 }]];

                                              [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The purpose of an alert is to give quick interactions or information. Why do you need an alert that doesn't go away?

Comment: because when i input wrong data, i click button register my UIAlertController will close. so i want to keep UIAlertController and show validate error when I input wrong data.

Comment: a) You probably want a separate window for that. You can use the interface builder b) Or, you can always just show another alert

Comment: I'd agree with @Arc676 's first point. If you need to display messages / warnings to the user, and allow them to try again. This needs to be done in a static full screen that the user cannot pass until success. Using popups for this style of task is not a great approach.

Comment: also, please format your code better in questions. Its hard to provide answers when the code is difficult to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible by default. Because default behavior dismiss the alert controller on action button click.

According to your need you should use tableview or custom view to manage registration.

Show custom view having text fields and buttons or table view to achieve this

`Alert controller` is not for this kind of task. It is only on behalf `alertview` or `actionsheet` and both's default behavior is to dismiss on click.

`Alert controller` doesn't have any delegate method also unlike `alertview` or `actionsheet`. so it is hard to manage it with alert controller.

Then also if you want to use alert controller only then you can show another controller from completion handler of it's action.

You should maintain record of previously filled textfields to show it on alert controller which presents again.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: thanks you, i call again [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil]; when i want to show Alert controller again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can't change default behavior of Alertcontroller. Either you have to use View for Register or you have to present another alert from action.